# Complex Json Object to Java object with Map field with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Json structure like so:

```
{
   "Pojo" : {
       "properties" : {
          "key0" : "value0",
          "key1" : "value1"
       }
   }
}
```

I want my final result to look something like this:

```
public class Pojo {
     public Map<String, String> properties;
}
```

but instead I get something like this:

```
public class Pojo {
   public Properties properties;
}

public class Properties {
  public String key0;
  public String key1;
}
```

Right now all I am doing for parsing the Json is this:

```
new Gson().fromJson(result, Pojo.class)
```

Thoughts on what I would need to do to get this set up correctly? I do not have the ability to change the Json return object's structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson is trying to match the JSON field name to a POJO field, so you above JSON is implying the top level object has a field named 'Pojo'.  In fact, it is indicating the following class structure,

```
class Container {
    MyObject Pojo;
}

class MyObject {
    Map<String, String> properties;
}
```

where the name of the classes `MyObject` and `Container` are completely arbitrary.  Gson matches field names, not object type names.

You can deserialize that object with a simple statement -

```
Container container = gson.fromJson(result, Container.class);
```

Your map with then be `container.Pojo.properties`

If you would rather not have the extra container class, you can parse to a Json tree first, and then extra the part that you an interested in --

```
JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(result);
// Note "Pojo" below is the name of the field in the JSON, the name 
// of the class is not important
JsonElement pojoElement = json.getAsJsonObject().get("Pojo");
Pojo pojo = gson.fromJson(pojoElement, Pojo.class);
```

Then your map is in `pojo.properties`, which is what I think you want. I have left off error checking for clarity, but you will probably want to add some.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand what Gson is trying to do here. This is my first attempt with the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONObject obj1=new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject obj2=obj1.getJSONObject("Pojo");
JSONObject obj3=obj2.getJSONObject("properties");
String key1=obj3.getString("key0");
String key2=obj3.getString("key1");
```

For more reference try the link:

https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/json-parsing-tutorial/